# How to solve a Semidefinite problem with fractional Objective function

Tags: semidefinite-programming

I have a Semidefinite problem of the form 
\begin{align}
           \min_{t\epsilon R,A \epsilon S_{+}^n}~& 1/t \\
&t>0\\
&A>=t C\\
&A\odot C_M=T_M\\
&\left\lvert\lvert A \right\rvert\rvert _F^2 <=r 
\end{align}
or a more general form 
\begin{align}
           \min_{t\epsilon R,A \epsilon S_{+}^n}~& 1/t+b t  \\
&t>0\\
&A>=t C\\
&A\odot C_M=T_M\\
&\left\lvert\lvert A \right\rvert\rvert _F^2 <=r 
\end{align}
Which matrices $C_M , T_M$ have many zeros and $ C >=0$ is a constant matrix. 
How to solve this without adding any other Semidefinite constraint to the problem?(Because it makes solving it slover). How to solve it efficiently?

Comment: You could just rewrite $\min 1/t$ into $\min -t,$ avoiding the fractional cost function.

Comment: Thank you. I want to know that is there any general method for solving fractional problems when there is a semidefinite constraints. Of course your suggestion works for simple cases like this.

Comment: Could you formulate the more general and more complicated case? I think this would be helpful.

Comment: I edit the question. But even in this simple case, could you go further in the method of substituting $-t$ instead of $1/t$. I have worked on this but unfortunately, I don't know how to proceed.